# How do i make the kdialog a certain width

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, kdialog

Im trying to make my first bash script and im trying to use kdialog .

How do i make the progress bar a certain width
 here is my attempt

```
dbusRef=`kdialog --title "Sweet As Buckup Demon" --progressbar "Initializing" 8`
qdbus $dbusRef Set "" value 1
qdbus $dbusRef setLabelText "Getting web site folder and creating mysqldump and grabbing configuration files from the apache Server"
cp -rf /usr/local/websites/sweetassurfwear /home/brett/sweetback/
sleep 4
qdbus $dbusRef Set "" value 2
cd /home/brett/sweetback/
```

And so on.. if you need the entire script i will post it

Basically at each part of the process it out puts text on the progress bar but the dialog keeps changing width.

How do i make the size standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--geometry` argument, e.g.

```
kdialog --geometry 300x300+300+300 --title "Sweet As Buckup Demon" --progressbar "Initializing"
```

You can see the documentation for this option by typing:

```
kdialog --help-all|grep geometry
```

Comment: `--geometry` option works for a limited set of dialogs only. `--textbox` and `--textinputbox` are among of them. In case of `--progressbar` it is silently ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use the `--geometry` option to widen an input box dialog and it wouldn't work. Eventually I found out that adding spaces to the end of the input box label forces the dialog to be wider, e.g. if you use

```
kdialog --title "Input dialog" --inputbox "Input"
```

You may get something like this:

[image: narrow input box dialog]

But if you add extra spaces at the of the input box label:

```
# The expression $(printf "%0.s " {1..70}) adds 70 space characters to the label
kdialog --title "Input dialog" --inputbox "Input $(printf "%0.s " {1..70})"
```

You'll get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately kdialog --geometry doesn't work. For a working example of how to fix up the geometry for a kdialog,
see https://github.com/rparkins999/kde-slow-start-wrapper.

Note this example sets the position: the width or height can be set by replacing the first or second -1 in the

`wmctrl -r $mytitle -e`

command.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a quirk in kdialog.

Try to start kdialog with the option

```
--progressbar "$(echo -e "\t\t\tYour window title here\t\t\t")"
```

Change the number of tabs (\t) in the window title to adjust the window width.